# MySql error: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've inherited a CodeIgniter query that generates this SQL

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`photo`, `users`.`rating`
FROM `pool_details`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `pool_details`.`captain_id`
WHERE `pool_details`.`pool_type` =0
AND `pool_details`.`pool_close` > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
GROUP BY `pool_details`.`captain_id`
ORDER BY `pool_details`.`members_count` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

> ERROR - 2020-01-02 18:39:42 --> Query error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY
>   clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'pool_details.members_count' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by - Invalid query:

Here is the same data with some "extra columns" and the offending clauses removed:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.email,users.rating,pool_details.members_count,pool_details.pool_type,pool_details.pool_close
FROM  pool_details
JOIN  users ON users.id = pool_details.captain_id
WHERE pool_details.pool_type = 0 AND pool_details.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
ORDER BY pool_details.members_count DESC;
//GROUP BY `pool_details`.`captain_id`
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | username | email                    | rating | members_count | pool_type | pool_close          |
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |           100 | 0         | 2020-01-04 03:00:00 |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |           100 | 0         | 2020-01-03 23:30:00 |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |           100 | 0         
...
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |             0 | 0         | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |             0 | 0         | 2020-01-03 00:30:00 |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |             0 | 0         | 2020-01-04 21:30:00 |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |             0 | 0         | 2020-01-03 03:00:00 |
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I want is to:

1. Show User's username, email and rating
2. Order by "members_count"
3. Show the user only *once*

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.username, users.email,users.rating
FROM  pool_details
JOIN  users ON users.id = pool_details.captain_id
WHERE pool_details.pool_type = 0 AND pool_details.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42';
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+
| id | username | email                    | rating |
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+
|  5 | wheel    | wheel@boxpik.com         | NULL   |
| 13 | Ronaldo  | pulisicblues07@gmail.com | 4.6    |
+----+----------+--------------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
<= This shows the users individually ... but it's *NOT* ordered by "members_count".
```

Q: Is there any combination of "GROUP BY" and/or "DISTINCT" that I can use with mySql 5.7 that will give me the result set I need?

Comment: if we know that `members_count` is functionally dependent (i.e. we know the value of `members_count` column from *all* rows in a collapsed group are the same), then we could just wrap in an aggregate function. .e.g  `ORDER BY MAX(pool_details.members_count) DESC`.  (we could use MIN() in place of MAX(), result will be the same, if we are guaranteed all rows in the collapsed group have the same value of `members_count`, then we know `MIN(members_count) <=> MAX(members_count)`

Comment: Which "members_count" of all that a user may have do you want to use in ORDER BY?

Comment: @spencer7593: That's the solution!  Thank you!  Here' s my updated SQL.  If you post it an an answer; I'd be happy to upvote and "accept" it. `SELECT users.id, users.username, users.email,users.rating
FROM  pool_details
JOIN  users ON users.id = pool_details.captain_id
WHERE pool_details.pool_type = 0 AND pool_details.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
GROUP BY pool_details.captain_id
ORDER BY MAX(pool_details.members_count) DESC;`

Comment: @FoggyDay:  my comment wasnt an answer to the question that was asked, if there is a combination of GROUP BY and DISTINCT ...   if `members_count` is not functionally dependent, then echoing the comment from forpas, which of the possible values for `members_count` do we want to use?  it's easy enough to pick out the maximum and minimum values with MAX and MIN , but maybe we want the value associated with the  earliest or latest `pool_close` ...  we're only guessing because we don;'t have a more precise specification

Comment: Sigh...  I didn't say "and"; I said "and/or". In the sense "whatever syntax eliminates the error".  You gave me the answer: "MAX()".  And that answer makes sense: we want an [aggregate](https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/).  Specifically: the captain with the most members should go at the top, the captain with the next most second, etc.  If you give a response, I'll "accept" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

A PHP/CodeIgniter application I inherited generated this SQL:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`photo`, `users`.`rating`
FROM `pool_details`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `pool_details`.`captain_id`
WHERE `pool_details`.`pool_type` =0
AND `pool_details`.`pool_close` > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
GROUP BY `pool_details`.`captain_id`
ORDER BY `pool_details`.`members_count` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

.. which, in turn, caused this MySql error:

> ERROR - 2020-01-02 18:39:42 --> Query error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY
> clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
> 'pool_details.members_count' which is not functionally dependent on
> columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by - Invalid query:

**Cause:**

forpas asked the right question:

> Which "members_count" of all that a user may have do you want to use in ORDER BY?

spencer7593 gave the right solution:

> If we know that members_count is functionally dependent ... then we could just wrap in an aggregate function. .e.g ORDER BY MAX(pool_details.members_count) DESC.

**Solution:**

Modified PHP/CodeIgniter query:

```
$this->db->select('users.id,users.username,users.email,users.photo,users.rating');
$this->db->from('pool_details');
$this->db->join('users','users.id = pool_details.captain_id');
$this->db->where('pool_details.pool_type',0);
$this->db->where('pool_details.pool_close >',$now);
$this->db->order_by('MAX(pool_details.members_count)','DESC'); // <-- Added "MAX()"
$this->db->group_by('pool_details.captain_id');
$this->db->limit(20, 0);
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

**Discussion:**
Each "Pool" has a "Captain".

We want to "group by" each individual captain among all the captains in all the pools.

The top of the list should be the pool with the most members.

The aggregate `MAX(pool_details.members_count)` gives us exactly the result we're looking for.

There's no "functional dependency"; the value of "members_count column" from all rows in a collapsed group are typically *NOT* the same.  Nevertheless, "MAX()" does exactly what we need: it resolves the error, and we get the results we want from the schema we have.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the `ORDER BY`, you seem to just want `EXISTS`.  That said, you can use another subquery in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM pool_details pd
              WHERE pd.captain_id = u.id AND
                    pd.pool_type = 0 AND
                    pd.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
             )
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(pd2.members_count)
          FROM pool_details pd2
          WHERE pd2.captain_id = u.id AND
                pd2.pool_type = 0 AND
                pd2.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
         ) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

EDIT:

You can also write this as:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT MAX(pd2.members_count)
        FROM pool_details pd2
        WHERE pd2.captain_id = u.id AND
              pd2.pool_type = 0 AND
              pd2.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
      ) as max_members_count
FROM users u
HAVING max_member_count IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY max_member_count DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Or:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT pd2.captain_id, MAX(pd2.members_count) as max_member_count
      FROM pool_details pd2
      WHERE pd2.pool_type = 0 AND
            pd2.pool_close > '2020-01-02 18:39:42'
     ) pd
     ON pd.captain_id = u.id
ORDER BY max_member_count DESC
LIMIT 20l
```

Comment: Thank you.  I took the liberty of fixing the typo in the second subselect, and changed `u.*` to `SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email, u.rating`.  At which point it does exactly what I wanted.  Q: Isn't "where exists()" and the two subselects inefficient?  FYI, I was *ALSO* able to fix the SQL error and get the results I wanted using spencer7593's suggestion:  `ORDER BY MAX(pool_details.members_count)`.  Isn't that far more efficient?

Comment: @FoggyDay . . . I added two equivalent methods.  To be honest, I hadn't noticed the `ORDER BY` when I answered the question and went back and added in the subquery.  With appropriate indexes, that might be a good approach, although the first query in the edit might have the best performance.